# Having an issue using the getline function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to utilize the `getline()` function twice in order to store a title of a book and then the name of the author in two separate variables which I would then use later to write this information to the file. However, whenever I run the program and arrive to the part where I am to add the book, it skips the input phase for Book Title and skips straight to Author (it blinks, letting me know I can input for the author but it never blinked for the title).

```
void LMS_Processing::addBook()
{
    fstream listingsFile;

    string title = "";
    string author = "";

    system("cls");

    listingsFile.open("listing.books", ios::out | ios::app);

    cout << "LMS: Edit - Add Book" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Book Title: ";
    getline(cin, title);

    listingsFile << title << ':';

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Author: ";
    getline(cin, author);

    listingsFile << author << ':';
    listingsFile << "in" << endl;

    listingsFile.close();
}
```

Basically, by following the procedure of the code it prints "Book Title: " and then ignores the fact that I put `getline(cin, title)` and then continues on.

Comment: Look to the right at the related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the code before this read any input from `cin`?  If so, it may not be consuming the most recent newline from `cin`, leaving it for the `getline()` in this function.

For example, if you have something like this in your code:

```
int option;
std::cout << "Enter option: << std::endl;
std::cin >> option;

if (option == 1)
     addBook();
```

then that code will leave a dangling newline waiting in the input, and the `getline()` in `addBook()` will read it.

Comment: I think you forgot something in your example there.  The input into `option`?

Comment: Yes, I did. My question turns out to be a duplicate. I added `cin.ignore();` after the cin that I use to receive the menu input and it solved the problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley : Yep... Missed that as dinner called me away too quickly.  ;-)